# SSL Certificate expired on server, Force Update Android app

Tags: android, tomcat, ssl

We have an SSL certificate installed on our servers, which got expired, The app was using SSL Pinning for the trusted CA. The app also has a feature of force update, which checks the app versions from the server over https which is not working anymore.

Is there anyway where we can bypass this certificate and force update the users to the new app without development on mobile client?

Server: Tomcat 7

Comment: I do not understand. If expiry of the server certificate requires a client update there is something seriously wrong with your application.

Comment: The update is required because of SSL pinning